# "<identifier> expected" in constructor method

Tags: netbeans, constructor

I'm just starting out with Netbeans and I ran into a problem trying to write a new class.

```java
public class DeliveryList<T> extends ArrayList<T>
{
    public DeliveryList<T> // <identifier> expected
    {
    }
}
```

Netbeans throws this error at me and I'm not quite sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - read [Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) tutorial pages.

```
class DeliveryList<T> extends ArrayList<T>
{
  public <T>DeliveryList() {}
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. Forgot to add parentheses. Can you explain why putting the generic before the name makes it work though? I tried it the other way but no dice.

Comment: Its [Generic constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)